# Imagens não utilizadas no projeto do android studio são incluidas no APK?

Tags: android, android-studio, imagem, apk

Normalmente eu não fico satisfeito com a primeira imagem que coloco como **background**, seja da activity, **textView**, **button**, etc. Até mesmo **imageViews** enfim.

Acontece que as deixo lá no projeto, mesmo não as utilizando, com o pensamento de que em dado momento posso precisar das mesmas, seja para um teste ou até mesmo uma comparação.

Essas são todas as imagens "drawable" de um projeto meu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acontece que quando fui passar o apk para o meu dispositivo android físico, eu achei o tamanho do apk muito grande em relação a aplicação que é bem simples na verdade. Por isso me surgiu a ideia de analisar o apk, dessa forma percebi que as imagens, mesmo as que não estavam sendo utilizadas, estavam sendo contabilizadas no peso do apk:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sinceramente não entendi o porquê das mesmas serem inlcuídas no apk. Engines de games como a **unity** por exemplo, excluem imagens e arquivos não utilizados do seu executável e da aplicação em si.

Gostaria de saber a explicação para isso, pois para mim não há sentido, deveria contabilizar no apk somente aquilo que é utilizado.

Comment: Deveria, mas não é. Cara o apk é como se fosse um zip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não se configurar o seu *app build.gradle* para esse efeito.

Deverá, para isso, utilizar as propriedades `minifyEnabled` e `shrinkResources` e "setá-las" com `true`:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Faça isso apenas no build final, antes de criar o APK para destribuição, já que isso aumenta o tempo de *build*.

Para mais informações veja [Shrink Your Resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#shrink-resources), na documentação.